# Getting weird error whilst populating an array

Tags: php, arrays

What I'm trying to do is transfer the contents of the array difference() to the array tempStore. The error I am getting is 'Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in' on line 4 ($tempStore($x) = $difference($x);). What am i doing wrong here and how do i fix it?

```
$difference = array("","","","","","","");

for ($x = 1; $x <= 6; $x++){
     $tempStore($x) = $difference($x);
}

for ($x = 1; $x <= 6; $x++){
     echo $tempStore($x);
}
```

Comment: Use [] instead of () for your arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use [] instead of ()

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 6; $x++){
    $tempStore[$x] = $difference[$x];
}
```